# How to use POST in Glue PHP Framework?

Tags: php, post, glue-framework

i'd like to create a simple login system with PHP and [Glue Framework](http://gluephp.com). my code is like this:

```
glue("route")->post("/login", function($params) {
    // I'm trying to catch the variable first
    echo $params['user'] .'aaand'. $params['pass'];
});
```

and the form is:

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
</form>
```

the question is, how can I catch these two variables - `user` and `pass`, then insert it to PHP Sessions ?

thanks for the answer and explanations!

Comment: Are you using a "framework" not maintained for 2 years ? https://github.com/aheinze/Glue

Comment: that php framework looks like jquery

Comment: As stated, you're using a framework that hasn't seen any action in a long long time. I'd suggest using http://www.slimframework.com/ instead

Comment: @flov because it seems lighter and easier to understand than codeIgniter, for example.

Comment: @AchmadMahardi Strongly consider taking a look at Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

### Sample login / logout code with(Captcha,CSRF) Protection

I will be honest with you, I love small footprints just like you. ^_^

It's okey if you want to learn how things works and start building something Secure and Simple.

Testing anything that come to this world and trying to break it, until you make something is impossible to Hack. ;)

First: make a folder and name it "**glue**" in your root of your Web Server.

Inside that folder make those files with the following contents:

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**glue.php**

```
<?php
/**
* glue
*
* Provides an easy way to map URLs to classes. URLs can be literal
* strings or regular expressions.
*
* When the URLs are processed:
*      * delimiter (/) are automatically escaped: (\/)
*      * The beginning and end are anchored (^ $)
*      * An optional end slash is added (/?)
*       * The i option is added for case-insensitive searches
*
* Example:
*
* $urls = array(
*     '/' => 'index',
*     '/page/(\d+)' => 'page'
* );
*
* class page {
*      function GET($matches) {
*          echo "Your requested page " . $matches[1];
*      }
* }
*
* glue::stick($urls);
*
*/
class glue {
    /**
     * stick
     *
     * the main static function of the glue class.
     *
     * @param   array       $urls       The regex-based url to class mapping
     * @throws  Exception               Thrown if corresponding class is not found
     * @throws  Exception               Thrown if no match is found
     * @throws  BadMethodCallException  Thrown if a corresponding GET,POST is not found
     *
     */
    static function stick ($urls) {
        $method = strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $found = false;
        krsort($urls);
        foreach ($urls as $regex => $class) {
            $regex = str_replace('/', '\/', $regex);
            $regex = '^' . $regex . '\/?$';
            if (preg_match("/$regex/i", $path, $matches)) {
                $found = true;
                if (class_exists($class)) {
                    $obj = new $class;
                    if (method_exists($obj, $method)) {
                        $obj->$method($matches);
                    } else {
                        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method, $method, not supported.");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Class, $class, not found.");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$found) {
            throw new Exception("URL, $path, not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?
/*
* This Login needs following things to make it secure:
* - HTTPS (Run login page on Encrypted Connection)
* - Protection against SQL-Injection
*/

session_start();

require_once("glue.php");

$urls = array(
    '/glue/' => 'index',
    '/glue/logout' => 'logout',
    '/glue/captcha' => 'captcha',
);

class index {

    function GET() {

        if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged'])){

            echo "<h1>Hello Again, {$_SESSION['name']}!</h1>";

            echo "<a href='/glue/logout'>Log Me Out!</a>";

        }else{

            $csrf = sha1(uniqid(time()));

            $_SESSION['csrf'] = $csrf;

            $form = " 
            <h1>Quick Login not Secure (needs HTTPS)</h1>
            <hr/>
            <form METHOD='POST'>
                <input type='hidden' name='csrf' value='$csrf'/>
                <label>User Name:</label><input type='text' name='username'/> <br/>
                <label>Password:</label><input type='password' name='pwd'/> <br/>
                <img src='/glue/captcha'/><br/>
                <label>Captcha:</label><input type='text' name='captcha'/> <br/>
                <input type='submit' name='Login' value='Login me in !'/>
            </form>
            ";

            echo $form;
        }
    }

    function POST(){

        if($_POST['username'] === 'test' && $_POST['pwd'] === 'test' && $_SESSION['captcha'] == $_POST['captcha'] && $_SESSION['csrf'] === $_POST['csrf']){

            echo "<h1>Salam {$_POST['username']}, You have logged Successfully...</h1>";

            echo "<a href='/glue'><h4>Goto Your page now</h4></a>";

            $_SESSION['is_logged'] = True;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];

        }else{

            echo "<h1>Failed to login, <a href='/glue'>try again</a></h1>";
        }
    }
}

class logout{

    function GET(){

        session_destroy();

        header('location: /glue');
    }
}

/* it does generate captcha and save it to session on the fly */
class captcha{

    function generatePassword($length = 5) {

        $code = rand(1000, 9999);

        $possibleChars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ" . $code;
        $password = '';

        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $rand = rand(0, strlen($possibleChars) - 1);
            $password .= substr($possibleChars, $rand, 1);
        }

        return str_shuffle($password);
    }

    function GET(){

        $code = $this->generatePassword();

        $_SESSION["captcha"] = $code;
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor(260, 24);
        $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); //background color blue
        $fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);//text color white
        imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
        imagestring($im, 5, 100, 5,  $code, $fg);
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
}

glue::stick($urls);
```

After you made all these files, you can access your tiny Framework via this URL:

```
http://localhost/glue

User Name: test

Password: test
```

I hope this Inspires you, **SALAM**

REF: https://github.com/jtopjian/gluephp